# Populate dropdown list using c# containing MySQL db table

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate the following dropdown list with information from MySQL database.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DeleteUsersList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DeleteUsersList_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I am using a .aspx source file for the html that contains the dropdown list.
I also have .aspx.cs file that contains C# code and I'm usying MySQL server for the database.

Basically I am trying to populate the dropdown list using a c# connection to MySQL database when the page is loaded. I have not been able to find anything specific with this information so if anyone can help me it would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Do you have a dataset of some sort already, or are you looking for a complete example?

Comment: please post related code in your .aspx.cs for us to check the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi check the following link to read about drop down example in asp.net

[Drop down list asp.net](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/aspnet-dropdownlist-control-examples-in.html)

Comment: This was useful however I cannot implement some of the commands for MySQL here...

Comment: hi if you want to use sql command in visual studio you should include these libraries. Using System.Data and Using System.Data.SqlClient.

Answer (score 2):

You could bind the DropDownList to a data source (DataTable, List, DataSet, SqlDataSource, etc) that you get from MYSQL database.

For example, if you wanted to use a DataTable:

```
private string GetConnection()
 {
     return "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=testdatabase";
 }

    private void LoadUsers()
    {

     DataTable rt = new DataTable();
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
     OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(GetConnection());
     OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, con);
     da.SelectCommand = cmd;
     da.Fill(ds);         
     rt = ds.Tables[0];


      DeleteUsersList.DataSource = rt;
      DeleteUsersList.DataTextField = "UserName";
      DeleteUsersList.DataValueField = "UserID";
      DeleteUsersList.DataBind();

     }
```

Comment: How do you implement the OdbcConnection statement  as well as the Obdc Command...?

I type it in but it doesn't even pick up this command.

Answer (score 0):

Execute "show tables" against your MySQL connetion. This will give you the list of available tables.